# send data through onclick event from child to parent React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React js I am pretty confused that how to send data through onclick event from child to parent component.

Parent Component

```
...
      onTurn(id){
            console.log(id)//undefined
        }
        renderCardsList(){
              const {cardsList} = this.props

              return cardsList.get('cards').map(({id,front_image}) => {
                  return  <Card
                            image={front_image}
                            onTurn={this.onTurn}
                            />
              })

            }
...
```

Child Component

```
const Card = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="singleCard">
            <div className="imageDiv">
                <img src={props.image} alt="work" />
            </div>
            <div className="bottombar">
                <span onClick={e => props.onTurn(props.id)} className="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" />
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" />
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: What specifically is confusing you? What goes wrong when you try this? (You may get better answers if you include a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/)).

Comment: Side note: There's no need (and no point) to pass `this` as the second argument to `map` if you use an arrow function for the callback; `this` will be inherited by the arrow function, and the one `map` tries to use when calling it will be ignored.

Comment: I am getting Undefined

Comment: (Despite my first comment above, I fail to see why this has been downvoted. I'd give the OP a chance to improve the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `onClick` expects an `id` property on `props`:

```
onClick={e => props.onTurn(props.id)}
```

But you're not providing one:

```
return  <Card
    image={front_image}
    onTurn={this.onTurn}
    />
```

So naturally, `props.id` in the card's `render` is `undefined`.

If you want the card to have an `id` on `props`, you'll need to specify one, e.g.:

```
return  <Card
    image={front_image}
    onTurn={this.onTurn}
    id={/*something*/}
    />
```

Comment: Such a dumb Mistake